# Mathematica: Print Text on 3D-Graphic

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, textures, graphics3d

I want to print a text on a cylinder. The result should look like a can of coca cola.

I tried it similar to an example in the mathematica documentation:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html > Scope > Texture Specification > Text Example

```
text = Style["Coca Cola", 128];
Graphics3D[{
   Texture[text],
   Red, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, radius[h], VertexTextureCoordinates -> {...}],

}]
```

But the Cylinder doesn't recognize the VertexTextureCoordinates-option.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, it just does not work with built-in primitives afaik. But you can surely write your own `Cylinder` function which is build from polygons where you can apply any texture you like:

```
text = Style["Cook a Cola", 128, White, Background -> Red];
Graphics3D[
 {Texture[text],
  Red, EdgeForm[],
  With[{dphi = Pi/35},
   Table[
    Polygon[{{Cos[phi], Sin[phi], 0}, {Cos[phi + dphi], 
       Sin[phi + dphi], 0}, {Cos[phi + dphi], Sin[phi + dphi], 
       1}, {Cos[phi], Sin[phi], 1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{phi/Pi, 0}, {(phi + dphi)/Pi, 
        0}, {(phi + dphi)/Pi, 1}
       , {phi/Pi, 1}}],
    {phi, 0, 2 Pi - dphi, dphi}
    ]
   ]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But my prof wants me to use the built in primitives. However this text idea was just an idea to earn some extra points.